# Can't get resourceStream from JSON file from the WebJob using the GetManifestResourceStream method

Tags: c#, json, azure-webjobs

In the Visual Studio 2017 I created a WebJob. I named that WebJob 'TaxSyncWebJob'

Right inside the TaxSyncWebJob project folder I placed the JSON file called taxonomy.json to read from

I am using the following code in an attempt to access that JSON

```
var resourceStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("TaxSyncWebJob.taxonomy.json");
```

However, the resourceStream returns null.

That code works in a simple console project

Is there a reason why I can't get JSON contents in WebJob using the GetManifestResourceStream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using this workaround

```
        string projectPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()));
        string contents = File.ReadAllText(projectPath + "\\taxonomy.json");
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps someone else. You need to update your csproj file to include those json files, or the assembly manifest wont find them on runtime.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="<path>\<to>\<file>\TaxSyncWebJob.taxonomy.json" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="<path>\<to>\<file>\TaxSyncWebJob.taxonomy.json">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Resource>
</ItemGroup>
```